# How to prevent AppBarLayout going behind the status bar?

Tags: android

The AppBarLayout is going behind the status bar. I have made navigation bar translucent. If I use fitSystemWindow then the content doesn't show below the navigation bar. I want to retain content below navigation bar and make the AppBarLayout below status bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_main_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/fragment_main_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:title="@string/app_name"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_main_tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:tabBackground="@android:color/white"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_unselected">

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/fragment_main_view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:src="@drawable/navbar_bottom"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: you can use toolbar  out of AppbarLayout .

Comment: But I also need the scrolling effect i.e. need the scrolling flags

Comment: you can put this in linear layout and also can in scrollview if your demands are like that.

Comment: that doesn't helps, something else?

Comment: i still have this problem, have you managed to find a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You should set android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to your top-level layout (in this case DrawerLayout)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CoordinatorLayout

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

> Formats: boolean
>
> Boolean internal attribute to adjust view layout based on system
>   windows such as the status bar. If true, adjusts the padding of this
>   view to leave space for the system windows. Will only take effect if
>   this view is in a non-embedded activity.

Comment: If i do this then, the content doesn't goes below the navigation bar

Comment: Sorry, I initially read that but didn't see the attribute in your code before I posted.  The AppBarLayout contains both the toolbar and the tabs.  Do you mean that the tab layout is going behind the toolbar?